# Most efficient way to filter an object with unknown keys

Tags: javascript, object

For an example we have a list:

```
const list = {
  "honda": "cars",
  "samsung": "electronics",
  "pear": "fruits"
}
```

If an user clicks at one of the options, we have to get the selected, and the not selected options from the list. I was thinking about this would be a very fast approach:

```
const filterObjectList = ({ target: { value } }) => {
  const { [value], ...notSelected } = list;
}
```

For an example the user selected `honda`.

```
list[value] === list.honda //true
```

According to the above example, my thought should be right, but it looks like it isn't (unexpected token...). What else can I use which is more efficient than `Object.keys().filter`?

Comment: *"If an user clicks at one of the options, we have to get the clicked, and the rest of the list."*  I don't understand what this statement is trying to say.

Comment: If I had to perform alot of array operations like `.filter()` on a collection, I would have the source data be an array to begin with and create an object for direct reference at the start instead of using Object.keys() every time I need a loop. Then again, if loop efficiency is that important, things like web workers or server side would be a way bigger gain than how to loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a variable to destructure your value into:

```
const filterObjectList = ({ target: { value } }) => {
  const { [value]: selected, ...notSelected } = list;
  // do something with selected and notSelected
}
```